# Session Auto logout Why?

Tags: php, session

I added a session limit timeout to my page. And later on I remove it, but anytime I access the said page it still functions as though I haven't removed the session limit. That means the limit is still active but doesn't exit.

- PROBLEM

Why, what have I not done?

```
$idle = xxx; 
$session_life = time() - $_SESSION['timeout_logout'];
if($session_life > $idle)
{ 
    session_destroy(); header("Location: index.php"); 
}
S_SESSION['timeout_logout']=time();

// without the session timeout code:

<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
    $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $msg = "You have been logout successfully.";
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
    //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
    $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
    unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
    unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
    unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

    $logoutGoTo = "index.php";
    if ($logoutGoTo) {
        header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this just a typo ? `S_SESSION` instead of `$_SESSION`, line 7.

Comment: yea typo not exactly so